# How can I read individual lines of a CSV file into a string array, to then be selectively displayed via combobox input?

Tags: vb.net, csv

I need your help, guys! :|

I've got myself a CSV file with the following contents:

```
1,The Compact,1.8GHz,1024MB,160GB,440    
2,The Medium,2.4GHz,1024MB,180GB,500    
3,The Workhorse,2.4GHz,2048MB,220GB,650
```

It's a list of computer systems, basically, that the user can purchase.

I need to read this file, line-by-line, into an array. Let's call this array csvline().

The first line of the text file would stored in csvline(0). Line two would be stored in csvline(1). And so on. (I've started with zero because that's where VB starts its arrays). A drop-down list would then enable the user to select 1, 2 or 3 (or however many lines/systems are stored in the file). Upon selecting a number - say, 1 - csvline(0) would be displayed inside a textbox (textbox1, let's say). If 2 was selected, csvline(1) would be displayed, and so on.

It's not the formatting I need help with, though; that's the easy part. I just need someone to help teach me how to read a CSV file line-by-line, putting each line into a string array - csvlines(count) - then increment count by one so that the next line is read into another slot.

So far, I've been able to paste the numbers of each system into an combobox:

```
Using csvfileparser As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser _
        ("F:\folder\programname\programname\bin\Debug\systems.csv")

            Dim csvalue As String()

            csvfileparser.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            csvfileparser.Delimiters = New String() {","}

            While Not csvfileparser.EndOfData

                csvalue = csvfileparser.ReadFields()

                combobox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{1}{0}", _
                                          Environment.NewLine, _
                                          csvalue(0)))

            End While

        End Using
```

But this only selects individual values. I need to figure out how selecting one of these numbers in the combobox can trigger textbox1 to be appended with just that line (I can handle the formatting, using the string.format stuff). If I try to do this using `csvalue = csvtranslator.ReadLine` , I get the following error message:

"Error 1 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'."

If I then put it as an array, ie: `csvalue() = csvtranslator.ReadLine` , I then get a different error message:

"Error 1 Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array."

What's the knack, guys? I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

Please go easy on me - and keep any responses ultra-simple for my newbie brain - I'm very new to all this programming malarkey and just starting out! :)

```
       Structure systemstructure

        Dim number As Byte
        Dim name As String
        Dim procspeed As String
        Dim ram As String
        Dim harddrive As String
        Dim price As Integer

    End Structure


 Private Sub csvmanagement()

        Dim systemspecs As New systemstructure

        Using csvparser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser _
        ("F:\folder\programname\programname\bin\Debug\systems.csv")

            Dim csvalue As String()

            csvparser.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            csvparser.Delimiters = New String() {","}

            csvalue = csvparser.ReadFields()

            systemspecs.number = csvalue(0)
            systemspecs.name = csvalue(1)
            systemspecs.procspeed = csvalue(2)
            systemspecs.ram = csvalue(3)
            systemspecs.harddrive = csvalue(4)
            systemspecs.optical = csvalue(5)
            systemspecs.graphics = csvalue(6)
            systemspecs.audio = csvalue(7)
            systemspecs.monitor = csvalue(8)
            systemspecs.software = csvalue(9)
            systemspecs.price = csvalue(10)

            While Not csvparser.EndOfData

                csvalue = csvparser.ReadFields()

                systemlist.Items.Add(systemspecs)

            End While

        End Using

    End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Thanks for your help guys, I've managed to solve the problem now.

It was merely a matter calling loops at the right point in time.

Comment: Don't use the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace  --- ugh.

Comment: Thank you for that informative suggestion, Cen. :P You shall be glad to hear that I have removed it.

Comment: Sorry! Fll off the radar over the long weekend... Di you sort it out? PK :-)

Comment: Yeah, finally managed it. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) to do the reading.
The binding shouldn't be an issue after that.

Here is the [Quickstart for Delimited Records](http://www.filehelpers.net/quickstart):

```
Dim engine As New FileHelperEngine(GetType( Customer))
// To Read Use:
Dim res As Customer() = DirectCast(engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt"), Customer())
// To Write Use:
engine.WriteFile("FileOut.txt", res)
```

When you get the file read, put it into a normal class and just bind to the class or use the list of items you have to do custom stuff with the combobox.  Basically, get it out of the file and into a real class asap, then things will be easier.

At least take a look at the library.  After using it, we use a lot more simple flat files since it is so easy, and we haven't written a file access routine since (for that kinda stuff).

Comment: Sorry, external libraries and that sort of stuff is way above my level right now.

Comment: and frankly, I'd rather get my head around the basics of VB before I start messing around that kind of stuff. Thanks for your help anyway though!

Comment: Well, all of System.* is a library, so better be careful then :)  This is probably the easiest and safest way, but I understand the desire to do it myself.  Best 'o luck!

Comment: Jesus you people edit old questions, you really gotta stop that.  This was *over* 5 years old, and didn't use generics on purpose.  Thanks for the correction of the link.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

I think your main problem is understanding how arrays work (hence the error message).

You can use `split` and `join` functions to convert strings into and out of arrays

`dim s() as string = split("1,2,3",",")` gives and array of strings with 3 elements
`dim ss as string = join(s,",")` gives you the string back

Comment: Sorry, I'm literally learning programming from scratch - I can't overstate how new to this I am, and so I really don't understand what you're saying. That MSDN site is the guide I've been using to get this far - and frankly I understand v. little of what it says!

Surely split and join would just take my lines and split them up or join them together? If that assumption is correct, I don't understand how that would help me, as I'd just take a line and divide it; I don't want to formatting my text, but simply take one line at a time then basically paste it into an array. :\

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's actually really good that you are using the TextFieldParser for reading CSV files - most don't but you won't have to worry about extra commas and quoted text etc...

The [Readline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readline(v=VS.90).aspx) method only gives you the raw string, hence the "Error 1 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'."

What you may find easier with combo boxes etc is to use an object (e.g. 'systemspecs') rather than strings. Assign the CSV data to the objects and override the "ToString" method of the 'systemspecs' class to display in the combo box how you want with formatting etc. That way when you handle the SelectedIndexChanged event (or similar) you get the "SelectedItem" from the combo box (which can be Nothing so check) and cast it as the 'systemspecs' to use it. The advantage is that you are not restricted to display the exact data in the combo etc.

```
' in "systemspecs"...
   Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
      Return Name ' or whatever...
   End Function ' ToString
```

e.g.

```
dim item as new systemspecs
item.ID = csvalue(1)
item.Name = csvalue(2)
' etc...

combobox1.Items.Add(item)
```

Let me know if that makes sense!

PK  :-)

Comment: This may be handy if you have not messed around with casting objects much: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CheatSheetCastingNET.aspx

Comment: I assume the item.id, item.name etc lines are references to a structure? 

Thankfully, I actually have something like this already in place; omitted it for brevity - 
structure systemspecs -- used as such: 
systemspecs.number = csvalue(0) 
systemspecs.name = csvalue(1)
...and so on... 
textbox1.appendtext(string.format(..., _
enviornment.newline, _ 
systemspecs.name, _ 
systemspecs.procspeed)( etc

Unfortunately, though: "Type 'CsvObject' is not defined." Plus I don't know how to "handle" "selectedindexchanged". Or how to override "ToString" methods... or how to cast "selecteditem"... :P

Comment: CsvObject is made by - sounds like the `systemspecs` structure you are using. The "selectedindexchanged" is a combo box event I assumed you were using, have a look at the combobox overview an it's members. events etc in MSDN. See updated answer...

Comment: Okay, inserting the Public Overrides etc inside my systemspecs structure has broken it. I also don't know what a return name is. I really can't stress how new I am to VB - indeed, you may just be better off rewriting my code to something that works, adding comments to explain the changes. :P (though I don't want to appear like I'm asking people to do my work for me!)

Comment: Ha ha- I know what you mean! if any of these concepts are new probably 'research' them first, e.g. if you are not sure about "Overrides" read up on it etc. When you know the base class libraries it makes things alot easier to know when we are talking your code vs ours etc.

Comment: I've updated my original post to display my current code. Unfortunately even the simplest of programming articles are way over my head, and time is at a premium, so research is a bit out of the option. I'm shocked there isn't some simple line of code that can do this kind of thing; -- csvalue(count) = csvtranslator.readline ... count = count + 1 -- would work wonders, and make my life so much easier. One day of my life has now been wasted on this crucial segment of code! Thanks for your help so far, Paul :) ...but any further assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Just check that you are creatting the structs inside your loop, otherwise it's the same object you are adding. I can't actually compile code at the moment but I'll look again tomorrow... PK :-)